# Closures and useCallback hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a more persistent version of closures (I know there are more efficient way to handle persistent data, I'm just trying new stuff).

```
 const reverseGrid = useCallback((() => {
        let counter = 3
        const updateCounter = ({ type}) => {
            switch (type) {
                case "INCREMENT":
                    return counter === refPreviousGrid.current.length ? refPreviousGrid.current.length : ++counter;
                case "DECREMENT":
                    return counter === 0 ? 0 : --counter;
                case "RESET":
                    counter = 3;
                    break;
                
            }
        }
        return updateCounter;
    }), [])()
```

In order to do so, I thought: "OK, now I'm going to scam JavaScript and use my value as a persistent/private data"

Of course I was the one who got scammed by JavaScript, because every time my function component renders, it also rerenders the reverseGrid function.

Can someone explain why this happens?  Shouldn't `useCallback` prevent this behavior?

Comment: you are executing the function reverseGrid every time. Hence it is updating. Try to remove () after the reverseGrid.

Comment: @deepak he is not executing reverseGrid every time, he is executing the useCallback function which returns another function that he uses it.